# Get results with Mongodb Nodejs driver and Express using find

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I have a tiny express server that I want to use to get some data from a collection in my database:

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/test';


async function myReport(schoolId) {
  const client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });

  try {
    await client.connect()
    console.log("Hello!"); // This is never ran unless I remove "await" from the above line :S 

    const db = client.db();

    const result = db.collection('states').find({}).map((a, b, c) => {
      console.log("This never runs", a, b, c);
      return "asdf";
    });

    return result;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
  }

  client.close();
};

// Hoisting server
app.get('/api/reports/states/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  const report = myReport(req.params.id)
  res.json(report); // {}
});

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  console.log(`reporting listening in`, PORT);
});
```

I really don't know what I'm doing wrong here. Tried using .each, toArray and I'm not able to get the actual results as a list.

I've been following these docs: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/Cursor.html

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The first issue I see is that you forgot an `await` here: `const result = db.collection('states').find({}).map`. You should use a callback inside `find()` or I suggest to `await` the `find()` result and then map it to what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your saying: 
`await client.connect()
 console.log("Hello!"); // This is never ran unless I remove "await" from the above line :S`

I think connection is not establishing. I tried your code with a little bit modification. I created a cluster on [Atlas Mongodb](https://mongodb.com) and used its URI as a connection string.

```
const express = require('express');
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
const app = express();
const PORT = 3000;
const MONGO_URI = 'mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0-oqotc.mongodb.net/<dbname>?retryWrites=true&w=majority';

 const getListings = async () => {
  const client = new MongoClient(MONGO_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true });
  try {
    await client.connect()
    console.log("Hello!"); // This will print now :-) 
    const listings = await client.db("sample_airbnb").collection("listingsAndReviews").findOne({});    
    return listings;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("ERROR", err);
  }

  client.close();
};


// Hoisting server
app.get('/api/get-listings', async function (req, res, next) {
  const report = await getListings()
  res.json(report); 
});

app.listen(PORT, (err) => {
  console.log(`reporting listening in`, PORT);
});
```

You need to change username, password and dbname with your ones. 
**Note:** While using Atlas Mongodb Cluster, if you are getting connection error, you need to whitelist your ip as well. 
Hope it will help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You defined myReport as an asynchronous function which returns a promise. Add toArray() back into your code and then get your report like this

```
app.get('/api/reports/states/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  myReport(req.params.id).then(report => {
      res.json(report);
  });
});
```

Because its the call to res.json is also in an asynchronous function I think you can also do

```
app.get('/api/reports/states/:id', async function (req, res, next) {
  const report = await myReport(req.params.id);
  res.json(report);
});
```